# Django - How to query and display multiple relationship struture

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm building a RSS feed reader where users can add own feeds and categories. I want to store content all of the the feeds in db and run a script that would fetch that content for all of the feed_url present in db periodically (I had working project where each feed is fetched live and it wasn't good idea)

Now after several attempts I got into the following model structure.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class Feed(models.Model):
    feed_url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.feed_url


class UserFeed(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, related_name='feed_posts')
    ## starting from here, my cronjob / script populates the data (using feedparser lib)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(max_length=512)
    dt_published = models.DateTimeField()
    dt_cached = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.feed, self.title)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-dt_published',)
```

What I'm looking for now is ability for pull into a view and later into templates, the following entities:

->Category -> Feed -> Posts

In my previous version where Feed and UserFeed fields were stored in one table/model, I had such view:

```
def category(request, category_id):
    user = request.user
    page_title = "Category: "
    category = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(id=category_id, user=user)).feed_set.all()
    category_name = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    context = {
        'page_title': page_title,
        'category': category,
        'category_name': category_name,
        }
    return expand_context_and_render(request, context, 'reader/category.html')
```

and this is my template:

```
{% for feed in category %}
    <p><a href="/reader/feed/{{ feed.id }} ">{{ feed.title }}</a></p>
    {% for post in feed.post_set.all|slice:"6" %}
        <p><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></p>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.dt_published|timesince }} ago.</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And it was working as intended.

Now, since I don't want to have multiple copies of feed_url in my database, I think the new models are OK, but I simply can't figure out how to query and display this new structure which has upstream and downstream relationships. I was looking at select_related but didn't get it to work. Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution myself. It's bit hacky :( but does the job.

```
def category(request, user_category_id):
    user = request.user
    page_title = "Category: "
    user_category = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(id=user_category_id, user=user))
    user_feeds = UserFeed.objects.filter(category=user_category, user=user)
    context = {
        'page_title': page_title,
        'user_category': user_category,
        'user_feeds': user_feeds,
        }
    return expand_context_and_render(request, context, 'reader/category.html')
```

and template:

```
{% for user_feed in user_feeds %}
    <p><strong><a href="/reader/feed/{{ feed.id }} ">{{ user_feed }}</a></strong></p>
        {% for post in user_feed.feed.post_set.all|slice:"6" %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <p><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title|truncatechars:"45" }}</a></p>
            <p>{{ post.content|striptags|safe|truncatechars:"85" }}</p>
            <p class="feed_date">{{ post.dt_published|timesince }} ago.</p>
            <hr />
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```